# Magento 2. Sales -> Invoices - add column to grid

Tags: magento2, grid, invoice, sales, column

How may i add column to Sales -> Invoices grid?

Answer (score 1):

This solution may be a bit more efficient and **100% tested working** since it follows the native way of adding a column to the grid, and you won't have to load every order displayed on the page to obtain the column data (utilising the **sales_invoice_grid** table instead). The above is a great example of how to create a customised renderer though.

**app/code/[vendor]/[package]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_invoice_grid.xml**

```
<!-- Add the column "custom_column" (Custom Column) to the sales invoice grid. -->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_invoice_columns">
    <column name="custom_column">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Please note that you must enable the column using the drop-down widget above the invoice grid before it appears.

**app/code/[vendor]/[package]/etc/di.xml**

```
<!-- Sync the column "custom_column" between the sales_invoice and sales_invoice_grid tables -->
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns">
            <item name="custom_column" xsi:type="string">sales_invoice.custom_column</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

**Sample setup code to add column to sales_invoice_grid table (use this in your install/upgrade script). The same code works for the sales_invoice table by the way.**

```
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable('sales_invoice_grid'),
        'custom_column',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Custom Column'
        ]
    );
```

For details information. Please check [Add column in Sales Invoice/Order grid in Magento 2](https://rohitkundale.wordpress.com/2017/02/26/add-column-in-sales-invoiceorder-grid-in-magento-2/)

Hope it helps you! :-)

Comment: how where you able to get this filtered?

Answer (score 0):

Can you following below link for salse invoice inside custom filed create

[sales invoice grid Code](https://rohitkundale.wordpress.com/tag/sales-invoice-grid/)